# Matrix representation for projection onto vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

> Let ${\bf w} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. There exists a $2$ by $2$ matrix ${\bf P}$ such that
>   $\operatorname{proj}_{\bf w} {\bf v} = {\bf P}* {\bf v}$, for all 2D vectors ${\bf v}$. Find ${\bf P}$.

I tried substituting variables for ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf P}$ and trying to calculate the problem from there, but it became messy and complicated fairly quickly. Any hints for a cleaner, quicker approach?

Comment: what does $\operatorname{proj}_{w}$ means?

Comment: Is $\text{proj}_w*u$ the projection of vector $u$ onto vector $w$? If so, it should be written $\text{proj}_wu$.

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado Sorry that was a typo, I edited my original problem statement.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Yes, thank you for correcting my typo! I edited it.

Comment: Write down the equations for the projection operation - that is if you have a vector (vx,vy), then what is the result of the projection operation in terms of vx and vy.  Assuming you have a matrix ( a b, c d ), what does a, b, c , d have to be? This can't be that messy, its only two dimensions!  There might be a more general proof using the scalar product of w and the general vector v is you don't like messiness.

Comment: @cockneywanker: Thanks, I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projecting a vector onto a vector can be done with the dot product, however this only gives the magnitude, however the projected vector will always point in the same direction of $\vec{w}$. In order to write this as an equation I will first normalize $\vec{w}$, such that the projection does not scale the input vector $\vec{v}$,

$$
\vec{w}_n = \frac{\vec{w}}{\sqrt{\vec{w}\cdot \vec{w}}}.
$$

The projection of $\vec{v}$ along $\vec{w}_n$ can now be written as,

$$
proj_{\vec{w}_n} \vec{v} = \vec{w}_n (\vec{w}_n \cdot \vec{v}).
$$

By substituting in the equation for $\vec{w}_n$ you get,

$$
proj_{\vec{w}} \vec{v} = \vec{w} \frac{\vec{w} \cdot \vec{v}}{\vec{w} \cdot \vec{w}}.
$$

If you use your vector for $\vec{w}$ and write $\vec{v}$ as $(v_1,v_2)$ you get,

$$
proj_{\vec{w}} \vec{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ -1
\end{bmatrix}
\frac{2 v_1 - v_2}{5}.
$$

This equation can be converted into an matrix multiplication,

$$
proj_{\vec{w}} \vec{v} = \frac{1}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 \\ -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\vec{v}.
$$

In general this matrix, $P$, can be calculated with,

$$
P_{ij} = \frac{w_i w_j}{\vec{w} \cdot \vec{w}}.
$$

Comment: You need to divide by sqrt(5), not 5.

Comment: @cockneywanker no because you have to divide twice by sqrt(5), once to normalize the vector $\vec{w}$ in front of the fraction and once to normalize the same vector which is used in the dot product. You can test this and see that it is correct if you for example choose $\vec{v}=\vec{w}$.